# Python Selenium: How to Stop While Loop When Reaching the End of a Scrollable div in Web Scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, while-loop

I'm working on a web scraping script using Python and Selenium. I have a while loop that scrolls a web page and collects restaurant data. I want to stop the loop when I've reached the end of the page, but I'm not sure how to detect that condition. Here's my code:

```
try:
    # Locate the scrollable div element for restaurant results
    scrollable_main_div = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@aria-label="نتائج عن restaurants in riyadh"]'))
    )
    
    i = 1 

    while True:
        # Scroll down to the end of the div
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrollable_main_div)
        time.sleep(2)

        # Locate and store a single restaurant element
        restaurant = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'(//div[@aria-label="نتائج عن restaurants in riyadh"]//div[contains(@class,"Nv2PK THOPZb CpccDe ")])[{i}]')

        # Get the restaurant's name
        name = get_name_check(restaurant)

        # Check for duplicate restaurant names
        if name not in restaurant_names:
            i += 1
            restaurant_names.append(name)
            print(name)
            print("_____________________________")

        time.sleep(1)

        # This condition is intended to stop scrolling when the end of the page is reached
        if driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop >= arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrollable_main_div):
            break

except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout Exception: Check the page or adjust the waiting time")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Create a DataFrame and save it to a CSV file
df = pd.DataFrame(restaurant_names)
df.to_csv("names.csv", index=False)
```

I have tried scrolling the div and collecting restaurant names, and I'm successfully storing the names in a restaurant_names list. However, I need help in adding a condition to stop the while loop when there's no more data to collect in the div so that I can create the DataFrame and save it to a CSV file.

Comment: This is Totally dependent on the website Element, you can wait till some finishing element arrives or something similar, if you can share the website It will make more sense!